# How to drag objects around in a Gtk.Fixed widget using mouse events?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I have a custom object(a small circle) placed at some point inside a Gtk.Fixed() widget .Is there a way to drag this object around using the mouse. I am not able to map the Mouse Press/Release/Motion events to make this work.

I would prefer solution in Python using PyGobject but any other language will do also be fine if explanation is provided

More Details:
I am trying to make a font editor where these objects I mentioned above will be the control points of the bezier curves in the Glyph outlines
Here is an image of the concept design:
https://github.com/sugarlabs/edit-fonts-activity/blob/gh-pages/files/img/wireframe_concept_01_first_prototype.svg
I need to able to move the points shown to edit the outline of the letter shown

Answer (score 2):

GtkFixed is not designed to do drawing work. It's made to locate widgets (such as buttons and such) on a fixed grid (á la Windows).

If you would like to move elements of a drawing, have a look at eg. GooCanvas. Each element on a goocanvas can have events connected, which can then be used to move it around. You can even use CanvasGroup to group primitives (circle, rectangle etc), and move them together (even change other properties such as color, linewidth). The toolbox actually contains curves etc. It's easy to create a 'handle' using a small rectangle.

[Here's an example](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/stable/goocanvas-simple-canvas.html) of a simple goocanvas program, and you can find download links, references manuals and other useful stuff [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GooCanvas).

I don't know if this is a tool you need, or just a learning exercise. If the former, then do have a look at [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), an open source font editor, and incredibly versatile.